# how do you detect a weak wireless signal from a windows mobile 6 app?

Tags: windows, mobile, wireless, detection, signals

I am using a Windows Mobile 6 based hand held device. 
I there a way to detect low or no wireless signal activity?
Since I cannot detect this, my application is getting exceptions and ultimately runs out of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting a weak wireless signal, you should probably instead detect when the Internet connection is becoming flaky (connections failing, requests taking a long time, etc). That way, regardless of the reason your app can't connect, your app can respond